# I want to prove $\lim_{x \to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}=1$

Tags: limits, analysis, solution-verification

i want to prove that
$$ \lim_{x \to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}=1 $$
using the definition of the limit.
I thought that if I say that |x|<δ (δ>0) with $x\in[-1,1]$ then
$$|\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}-1|=
|\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+1}+ \sqrt{1-x}}-1|<
|\frac{2-\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+ \sqrt{1-x}}|=
|\frac{2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{x+1}+ \sqrt{1-x}}|=
\frac{2x^2}{(\sqrt{x+1}+ \sqrt{1-x})(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}
$$
then because
$1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1$
I can say that
$$\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}+ \sqrt{1-x}}<
x^2(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})$$
I know that $\sqrt{1-x}\ge 0.$
Therefore  $$x^2(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})<x^2\sqrt{1+x}$$
So, having |x|<δ $$δ^2\sqrt{δ+1}=ε$$

Comment: Everything you've written is correct until your claim that $\left | \frac{2\sqrt{x+1}}{x+1} \right |<|2\sqrt{x+1}|$, which is false for e.g. $x=0$. (It's *very* false for e.g. $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.)

Comment: The easiest way I'd compute this limit, by the way, would be to observe that it is by definition $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} (f(x) - f(0))$, where $f(x) := \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{1-x}$; then use the chain rule etc.

Comment: @PatrickStevens thank you for your comment. I hope you find the current solution more satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to rationalise the given function with $$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{1-x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

To restate the problem to make it easier to reference:
$$
\text{I want to prove }\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}=1
\tag{Eq. 1}$$
The precise [definition of the Calculus Limit is given at the California SFU College website as](https://www.sfu.ca/math-coursenotes/Math%20157%20Course%20Notes/sec_LimitsFormal.html):

> [image: Definition of a Limit]

To Quote From the University of California Site on **Hopital's Rule**:

[DETERMINING LIMITS USING L'HOPITAL'S RULES](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/lhopitaldirectory/LHopital.html)

> THEOREM 1 (L'Hopital's Rule for zero over zero): Suppose that
> $$\lim_{x→a}f(x)=0\text{ , }\lim_{x→a}g(x)=0 \text{ , }$$ and that
> functions $f$ and $g$  are differentiable on an open interval I
> containing $a$. Assume also that $g′(x)≠0$ in $I$.  If $x≠a$ Then
> $$\lim_{x→a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x→a}\frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}$$ so long
> as the limit is finite, $+∞$, or $−∞$. Similar results hold for $x→∞$
> and $x→−∞$.

Referring to these referenced proofs, set:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x} \text{ and } g(x)=1 \text{ and } a=0\tag{Eqs. 2}$$
$$\lim_{x→(a=0)}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=$$
$$=\lim_{x→(a=0)}\frac{f′(x)}{g′(x)}=$$
$$=
\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x})\right)}
{\frac{d}{dx} x}|_{x→(a=0)}
\tag{Eqs. 3}$$

$$=
\frac{
 \frac{1}{2}
 \left(
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}
  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}
 \right)
 }
{1}|_{x→(a=0)}
\tag{Eq. 4}$$
Finally,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}=
\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac{
 \frac{1}{2}
 \left(
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}
  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}
 \right)
 }
{1}
=
\lim_{x \to 0}
\frac{
 \frac{1}{2}
 \left(
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{0+1}}
  +\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0}}
 \right)
 }
{1}=1$$
So it immediately follows that (as was to be proven):
$$
\boxed{
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}- \sqrt{1-x}}{x}=1 
}
\tag{Eqs. 5}$$